# Duplicates while Processing Streaming Data using Kafka-Spark Streaming API

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, offset, kafka-consumer-api

The below code works and commit offset after the data processing.
But the issue is, it is processing duplicates in the below case:

The consumer job is running and the hive table has 0 records and the current offset is(FORMAT- fromOffest, untilOffset, Difference):
512 512  0

Then i produced 1000 records, and by the time it read 34 records but not committed, i killed it
512 546  34

I see that by this time, the 34 recs has already been loaded to the Hive table

Next, i restarted the application.

I see that it again reads the 34 records(instead of reading 1000-34=76 recs) although it has already processed them and loaded to Hive
512 1512  1000
And then after few seconds it gets updated.
1512 1512  0
Hive now has (34+1000=1034)

This causes duplicates records(extra 34) in the Table.
As mentioned in the code, i am committing the offset only after processing/loading to Hive table.

```
public void method1(SparkConf conf,String app) 
    spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(conf.get("")).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
    final JavaStreamingContext javaStreamContext = new JavaStreamingContext(context,
            new Duration(<spark duration>));
    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(javaStreamContext,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String> Subscribe(<topicnames>, <kafka Params>));

            JavaDStream<String> records = messages.map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> tuple2) throws Exception {
                    return tuple2.value();
                }
            });

            records.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
                    if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
                        methodToSaveDataInHive(rdd, <StructTypeSchema>,<OtherParams>);
                    }
                }
             });

             messages.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
              @Override
              public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rdd) {
                    OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
                    ((CanCommitOffsets) messages.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);                     
                    for (OffsetRange offset : offsetRanges) {
                        System.out.println(offset.fromOffset() + " " + offset.untilOffset()+ "  "+offset.count());
                    }
                     }
              });             
    javaStreamContext.start();
    javaStreamContext.awaitTermination();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when building a Spark Streaming job you should not be concerned with duplicates, that should be handled downstream. Don't get me wrong, you want to build your application to prevent duplicates but when catastrophic things happen you're going to get duplicates, which is why it's  best to manage that later.

The first issue I see is where you're saving your offsets. You should be saving them right after you save the data, not in a method after that. When records.foreachRDD finishes the methodToSaveData it should then make a call to save the offset. You'll probably need to restructure how you are mapping records so you have the offset details, but that's the best place for it.

```
        records.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
                if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
                    methodToSaveDataInHive(rdd, <StructTypeSchema>,<OtherParams>);
                    **{commit offsets here}**
                }
            }
         });
```

That said, it does not matter where you save the offsets. If the job is killed after it has written data to hive and before the offset range is committed, you are going to re-process records. There are certain ways you can build the application so it has graceful shutdown hooks (Google it) that try to catch a kill command and gracefully shut it down, but again that is vulnerable to how the app is killed or crashes. If the machine running the executor looses power after it's save to hive but before the offset is committed, you've got duplicates. If the app is killed -9 (in Linux), it doesn't care about a graceful shutdown and you'll have duplicates.